# I am not able to assign value to a string storage and retrieve the set value

Tags: solidity, truffle

below is the test.sol file

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract test {

    string initialstring = "Hello World!";

    function getstring() public view returns(string memory){
        
        return initialstring;

    }

    function setstring(string memory newstring) public  returns(bool success) {
        initialstring = newstring;
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the test case written in truffle js

```
const Test = artifacts.require("test.sol");

contract('Test',(account) => {
    it('Reading Default value', async() => {

        let TestContract = await Test.deployed();
        let orgstring = await TestContract.getstring.call();
        assert.equal("Hello World!", orgstring, "Initial Say Matches");
    });
    it('Inserting new value', async() => {
        let TestContract = await Test.deployed();
        let setstatus = await TestContract.setstring.call("Hi World");
        assert.equal(true,setstatus, "New Value inserted");
        let Newphrase = await TestContract.getstring.call();
        assert.equal("Hi World",Newphrase, "Updated value received");
    });

});
```

The second test case fails and I am not able to comprehend why it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.call()` only for contract methods which are not updating the state of the contract ( such method marked with `view`, `pure` keywords ).

Try this:

```
const Test = artifacts.require("test.sol");

contract('Test', (accounts) => {
    it('Inserting new value', async() => {
        return Test.deployed()
        .then(function (instance) {
            return instance.setstring("Hi World", {from: accounts[0]});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Miroslav it worked now both my test cases are passing